# Estructura HTML para cargar artículos con distintas estructuras desde PHP

Tags: php, html

Buenas,

Tengo una duda referente a cómo debería ser la estructura HTML en una web que cargue artículos desde PHP. Si todos los artículos tuviesen la misma estructura, por ejemplo, una foto, un extracto del artículo, el artículo y una imagen dentro, no tendría problemas...pero los artículos lo normal es que algunos tengan 2 fotos, otros 5, otros ninguno...tengan citas para resaltar cosas importantes del artículo...etc.

Es en esta situación cuando no sé cómo hacer para que pueda guardar los artículos en una base de datos y cargarlos con PHP. Lo único que se me ocurre es tener 4-5 plantillas en función del artículo y cargar una u otra...

Pongo un ejemplo:

http://www.3djuegos.com/juegos/analisis/17732/0/resident-evil-7/

Tienen varias fotos, citas, videos...

Aquí otro ejemplo de otra página:

http://www.eurogamer.es/articles/gwent-avance

Entiendo que el artículo en su totalidad habría que guardarlo en la misma celda de la base de datos.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), 
puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada o puesta en espera no se lo tome a mal, 
para mas información consulte el siguiente [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). 
Saludos

Comment: Hola podria tener una respuesta pero mejor te hago este comentario...cada quien tiene una metodologia de trabajo diferente y cada quien trabaja a su gusto, mi opinion personal es que si lo que quieres es publicar paginas como los ejemplos que has dado no veo necesario que uses bases de datos simplemente es cuestion de estilos css y html...ya si tu lo que realmente deseas es hacer cierto tipos de 'post' enn cualquier momento...ya lo que realmente deberias de pensar es en realizar un tipo de aplicativo, el cual tengas tus propias paginas...

Comment: en la que tu puedas ingresar informacion, subir archivos(imagenes,videos,etc,) y que se guarden en la base de datos y ya desde la parte menos conveniente hacer bucles que traigan los datos que desde la base de datos y los implementes en tus archivos 'html' que en realidad deberian de trabajar con extension php.

Comment: Que tal usar un Editor WYSIWYG como Bootstrap Summernote WYSIWYG Editor y todo eso lo cargas en tu registro de post, como guardarias el contenido con el formato, ya solo lo deberias de imprimir en tu pantalla de post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar editores de texto enriquecido, su función es guardar el *HTML* que generes en la base de datos.

Aquí te coloco una página con varias opciones:

http://valenciadisenoweb.blogspot.com/2014/12/20-excelentes-editores-de-texto.html

Comment: Buenas, le he estado echando un vistazo aunque sigo sin verlo claro. Imagino que es un sistema muy parecido al del cajetín de comentarios que se puede ver en muchos foros, y que todo eso que escribes junto con elementos de HTML se guarda en la base de datos como bien dices. ¿Lo suyo sería entonces crear una sección de amdnistración o algo por el estilo para crear y guardar los artículos en base de datos? Gracias!

Comment: Si exactamente aunque el tema mas delicado son las imágenes, puede implementarse una idea estilo Wordpress donde tu tengas un modulo para cargar imágenes y el texto enriquecido llames la dirección de la imagen, saludos.